# JTabbedPane adding null components

Tags: java, jpanel, jtabbedpane

Riddle me this: I have a JTabbedPane that has custom JPanels in it. When I try and access those JPanels, all I get back is null. I know that the panels have been added because on the UI I can see the tabs. I can also interact with the panels and switch between tabs. It doesn't matter how I add these JPanels, it always returns null.

Now I could just keep an ArrayList of the JPanels on the side for processing, but I would think that would kinda defeat the purpose of the JTabbedPane keeping any kind of model.

Does anyone know what's going on with this?

Comment: Please can you add the code to show how you are adding the JPanels and how trying to 'access those JPanels'.

Comment: conversationTabs is the JTabbedPane.
conversationTabs.getTabComponentAt(i)

I'm adding the tabs like so:
conversationTabs.addTab("Blah", (instance of the JPanel))
conversationTabs.insertTab("Blah", null, (instance of the JPanel), "", 0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong method: `getTabComponentAt(int)` will return the `Component` used to render the actual tab itself (if you've specified one).  You should call `getComponentAt(int)` instead.  I've done exactly the same thing myself before!